# Construct a matrix from blocks of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I am trying to find eigen values of a matrix system where entries of the matrix are also matrix. This is how my matrix looks:

$$ M=\begin{bmatrix}
           H[j,j] & T[j,j+1] & 0 &0 &...\\
         T[j+1,j] & H[j+1,j+1] & T[j+1,j+2] & 0&...\\
         0 &T[j+2,j+1]&H[j+2,j+2]&T[j+2,j+3]&...\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here $H[j,j]=\cos(j)I_{4\times4}$
is a $4\times4$ matrix,

$I_{4\times4}$ is a $4\times4$ identity matrix, and $$T[j,j+1]=T[j+1,j]=\sin(j)I_{4\times4}$$ ... is also a four by four matrix where $j$ goes from $0$ to $10$.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `M` is the Kronecker product of `I` (4x4) and a 10x10 matrix of cos and sin terms. Consequently, the eigenvalues are the product of the eigenvalues of the 2 matrices

Comment: Dear @mikado the choices of matrices are just a simplified assumption. My problem is not that simple. In my case the entries are even in off diagonal terms of the matrices. But I have put it there to ask it in a most simplest way. I am expecting to see concatenating type solution of this problem.

Comment: What is the `Dimensions` of `M`?

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ the dimension of M is $$40\times40$$.

Comment: @HazoorImran Now that `M` is 40-by-40, isn't `j` from 1 to 10 rather than from 0 to 10?

Comment: "My problem is not that simple." - OK, so what does your *block tridiagonal matrix* actually look like? How complicated can the individual blocks get?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have got your attention properly, but you can see if code below works for you or not,

```
matM = Module[{block, n = 4, jup = 10},
  block[i_, j_] := Which[i == j, Cos[i],
     Abs[i - j] == 1, Sin[Min[i, j]],
     True, 0
  ] IdentityMatrix[n];
  SparseArray @ ArrayFlatten[Table[block[i, j], {i, (*0,*) jup}, {j, (*0,*) jup}]]
]
```

Comment: No this does not create the right entries. I have checked it by matrix form.

Comment: @HazoorImran So what is not correct?

Comment: This is creating first four column with entries 1 along diagonal.

Comment: @HazoorImran According to the dimension you spoke about, I guess it that `j` does not take 0 value. How about the code now?